# Getting exception for juint socket servlet test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have created socket server and client class and executing successfully. While creating JUnit test class for the socket sever and client i am getting any result.
i'm guessing its waiting for client request but after creating client also its not execute.

Server class at

> PrimaryKeyValueStore.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import college.Student;

public class PrimaryKeyValueStore {

    private InMemoryCache inMemoryCache;

    public PrimaryKeyValueStore() {
        inMemoryCache=new InMemoryCache();
    }

    public void startServer(int port) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
        ObjectInputStream inputStreamFromClient=null;
        Socket clientSocket=null;

        try {
            serverSocket=new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                clientSocket=serverSocket.accept();

                inputStreamFromClient=new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                Student student=(Student) inputStreamFromClient.readObject();

                switch(student.getRestMethod()) {

                case "PUT": inMemoryCache.put(student.getUserName(),student);
                new Thread(new PrimaryKeyValueStoreClient(clientSocket,Collections.EMPTY_SET)).start();
                break;

                case "GET": new Thread(new PrimaryKeyValueStoreClient(clientSocket,inMemoryCache.get(student.getUserName()))).start();
                break;

                case "DELETE": Set<Student> setStudent=inMemoryCache.get(student.getUserName());
                inMemoryCache.delete(student.getUserName());

                new Thread(new PrimaryKeyValueStoreClient(clientSocket,setStudent)).start();
                break;

                case "GETALL": new Thread(new PrimaryKeyValueStoreClient(clientSocket,inMemoryCache.getAll())).start();
                break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server Error :: "+e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Localized :: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.err.println("Stack Trace :: "+e.getStackTrace());
            System.err.println("To String :: "+e.toString());
        }finally {
            if(inputStreamFromClient!=null) {
                try {
                    inputStreamFromClient.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(serverSocket!=null) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the client class was

> CollegeClient.java

```
public class CollegeClient {

    private static final String SOCKET_IP="127.0.0.1";

    public Set<Student> sendMessage(Student student, int port) {

        Socket clientSocket=null;
        ObjectOutputStream outToServer=null;
        ObjectInputStream fromServer=null;

        try {
            clientSocket=new Socket(SOCKET_IP, port);   
            outToServer=new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.writeObject(student);

            fromServer=new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            Set<Student> employeeSet=(Set<Student>) fromServer.readObject();

            return employeeSet;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client Error :: "+e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Localized :: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.err.println("Stack Trace :: "+e.getStackTrace());
        }finally {
            if(clientSocket!=null) {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(fromServer!=null) {
                try {
                    fromServer.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(outToServer!=null) {
                try {
                    outToServer.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my test class was,

```
public class CollegeClientTest {

    private CollegeClient collegeClient;
    private PrimaryKeyValueStore primaryKeyValueStore;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        collegeClient = new CollegeClient();
        primaryKeyValueStore=new PrimaryKeyValueStore();
    }

    @Before
    public void serverStart() {
        primaryKeyValueStore.startServer(9000);
    }

    @Test
    public void sendMessage() {

        int port=9000;
        Student student=new Student();
        student.setUserName("a");
        student.setFirstName("aa");
        student.setLastName("aaa");
        student.setAge(1);
        student.setMark(100);
        student.setRestMethod("GET");
        Set<Student> employeeSet=collegeClient.sendMessage(student, port);
        System.out.println("===>> "+employeeSet);
    }

}
```

and the result was,

[image]

Can anyone help to solve this issue.

Comment: please post your result as a text and not image, moreover the exception is not visible in your image too

Comment: Hi Dhawal, i'm not receiving any exception message its in hold state.

Answer (score 0):

You have used 2 `@Before` method in your test. Junit does not guarantee the execution order if multiple `@Before` methods are declared. There may be a chance that your method that starts the server is called before client is initialized itself.

Moreover you don't need to initialize your classes (CollegeClient, PrimaryKeyValueStore) in setup method you can do that at time of declaring itself.

Try initializing classes at declaration time only one `@Before` to start your server and then run your test case.

Comment: After the changes while triggering two times means getting response. Any option to get response for single trigger.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please update your question with your latest change. Are you getting a response now?